# Emacs mode for R?

Tags: emacs, r

Is there a mode in emacs that does syntax highlighting for the R programming language? R-mode doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, there is:  [**ESS**](http://ess.r-project.org).

And it is very highly recommended.  And it does *a lot* more than just syntax highlighting so please read the [docs](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html).

*Edit:* Some ten+ years later, installation got easier too:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents ENTER
M-x package-install ENTER ess ENTER
```

You may want some related packages, eg poly-mode is good for markdown support, but this is a start.

Comment: In case you want to install it, "ess" is available on melpa's packages. `M-x package-refresh-contents ENTER`, followed by `M-x package-install ENTER ess ENTER`. As of March2019, for emacs 25.1 and newer only.

Comment: @init_js you should make that a separate answer as this should be the preferred approach asof 2019

Comment: I get no match for ess.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen There is a link in my ten+ year old answer, and the link still works.  These days you also get ess at melpa and other Emacs code repos if you are into that.

Comment: In Ubuntu, I was able to get it to work by installing the Ubuntu/Debian package `ess`: `sudo aptitude install ess`.

Comment: Sure. I am the maintainer of that one. `ess` is actually transitioned to `elpa-ess` just like many other Debian / Ubuntu packages for Emacs.